# Need to find out a formula for calculating the influence score of a poetry based on certain criterias

Tags: algorithm

Help me to solve this one.
For a poem competition in the arts festival of our college, we need to find out a best one based on certain criterias.Our actual plan is to post all the contributions(poems) of the students into our college site and based on the responses from students reviews given points to each poem.

Criterias for giving points to poems based on -:

```
     1) Repeated visits (same visitors visit a poem many times and posting comments etc).
     2) Unique visit (Any visitor that visit a poem).
     3) Rating given for a poem (Feedback of a user is shown by this-upto 5 stars).
     4) Sharing it through mail,twitter facebook etc (sharing this poem through their social networking sites account).
     5) Flag it (select the category that reflects concern about this,whether it violates our privacy).
```

Based on these factors we need to calculate the influence score of the poem.

All the four factors except flag is considered as positive factors for influence score.For rating and sharing of a poem, we think give double importance than the unique visitors.Repeated visit also has importance than unique visitors. Likewise flag a poem ( high negative factor)- has double negative effect (like the positive double effect of sharing and rating).

Please help us to find out  a formula for calculating the Influence score of a poem.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to check the poems in advance rather than asking students to flag them if they contain inappropriate material?  Either way, I don't think including flags in the score would be sensible - if you are explaining the scoring system to the students in advance (which would probably be a good idea), wouldn't they simply see flagging as a way of downvoting?  You also haven't specified how the repeated visits score would work.

Comment: obviously a score function would be some sort of weighted sum like `score(p) = x1 * repVisits(p) + x2 * uniqeVisits(p) ....` Do you want us to suggest weighing factors or what?

Comment: Um. If this is supposed to select the "best" poem in any sense, then you're relying *very* heavily on the contributors to "play fair". They could even "cheat" by accident, for example contributors who reply to comments on their own entry will tend to generate more comments, but this has nothing to do with their poem. Should answers try to alter your scoring system to make it a contest of poetry rather than a contest of social media marketing?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way of finding a best poem is indeed to use a score based on a weighted sum of points. If you want alternative methods, there is a whole zoo out there, and one starting point is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-criteria_decision_analysis. The Sage handbook "Multiple Attribute Decision Making - An Introduction" by Yoon and Hwang is short and readable.

The problem with trying to provide a particular answer to this is that the question is really about you deciding what you mean by the best poem, and probably only you - or the users of your site - can decide that.

I note that, ahead of time, you may not know what scores to expect - e.g. how many repeat visits a good poem will get. One way to get round this problem is not to use the number of repeat visits, but the ranking of the number of repeat visits - e.g. with N poems, score N for the poem with the highst number of visits, N-1 for the poem with the next highest number of visits, and so on, scoring ties as the average of the scores that would have been given if there wasn't a tie.